# Django Exception

Tags: python, django

I have a question. I'm working on a Web-app and I included the *Google API*. Everything works fine and now I want to add some stuff for good Messages for the users.

The Problem now is, that I built a `try - except` with the request inside:

```
try:
   results = service.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10,
                            orderBy='email').execute()  
   response = HttpResponse.status_code
except Exception:
   return "error"
```

In this case, response is 200, that's good.

But when I make a bad request like:

```
try:
   results = service.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10,
                            orderBy='wdadwadwa').execute()  
   response = HttpResponse.status_code
except Exception:
   return "error" #I want to return the error code here
```

Or I use a wrong scope I always get a code 200. Actually It's right because we have the `try-except` block in place. However I need the original error code such as `404`, `403` in order to return a detailed messages to users. e.g `403 - better contact the admin`.

How can I get the original error's http response since `HttpRespone.status_code` doesn't work in this case ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay i fixed it now. So i found HTTPError and tried to implement that. Nothing works. After a while i found that google has their own HttpError. So guys when you try to work with try-except and google api stuff use:

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

and now:

```
try: 
   results = service.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10,
                            orderBy='email').execute()  
   success = HttpResponse.status_code
except HttpError as err:
   return err.resp.status 
else:
  return success
```

Now you are able to catch few things like bad request or no authorized etc.
In case of success, you can return success which is in this case 200 for everything is good. 
After that you can give good feedback to your users x)